# layout jupyter notebook with jupyter-lab

Tags: html, layout, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm using jupyter-lab with R kernel which I find much more friendly than Rstudio to do some analysis.

But I have some trouble when it comes to export the document into nice html file.

Here is what I have before exporting :

[Before exporting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gpvL.png)

And here is an extrait of the html file :

[After exporting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqwLN.png)

How could I keep a form similar as before exporting ?

More generally, I'm looking for reference that explains how to make a nice html document when using Jupyter-lab with the R kernel.